# Why is that node modules built through npm are included in .dockerignore in many tutorials, dont we need them to run our app

Tags: angular, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerise an angular application. This is my docker file

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ppone/frontend

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build --prod

RUN npm install pm2 -g

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/ppone/server

EXPOSE 8126

RUN npm install

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "NodeServer.js"]
```

With *npm install*, node_modules will get created. Do i need to ignore these *node_modules*. Why is that these are ignored in many tutorials:
https://wkrzywiec.medium.com/build-and-run-angular-application-in-a-docker-container-b65dbbc50be8

https://www.fosslinux.com/24962/creating-dockerfiles-dockerignore-and-docker-compose.htm

This is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
     image: mongo:4.4.2
     container_name: mongo
     ports:
       - "27017:27017"
  service1:
     image: image1
     container_name: mycontainer
     build: ./server1/proj1
     ports:
       - "80:8126"
     links:
       - "mongo"
     depends_on:
       - "mongo"
     command: ["/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh", "localhost:27017", "--", "pm2-runtime", "NodeServer.js"]


  service2:
     image: image2
     container_name: myserver
     build: ./server2/proj2
     ports:
       - "81:8125"
     links:
       - "mongo"
     depends_on:
       - "mongo"
     command: ["/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh", "localhost:27017", "--", "pm2-runtime", "NodeServer.js"]
```

Also, please suggest if there are any best practices i need to follow in these files

Comment: There is nothing that says you can't include the node_modules folder if you want. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: The Docker OS might not be the same as your local OS (e.g. I'm building Alpine images from macOS) in which case any modules with native code won't work. You also want to check that it'll build in a clean environment, not because of some state in your `node_modules/` locally. Given that you're building an SPA then serving it, I'd recommend more of a multi-stage build (see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/main/Dockerfile).